# How do I organise my Arduino code libraries

Tags: c++, arduino

I hope for some advice in organising my code and structuring my classes/objects.

I've been writing Arduino sketches for some time now, but I want to start a project that is going to be a little to big for one sketch file. I know I can organize my code in different files, adding classes in .cpp and .h files.

There is an LCD screen attached to my project, so I'd like to handle all LCD code in one place. I can make a class out of this with some public methods for writing to the screen and so on. The object initializes a LiquidCrystal object by itself, so far no problem: My main sketch has a variable called LCD which is a pointer to the LCD class for example and I can use an expression like LCD->print("test"); to print something on the LCD.

I can't get my head around how to do other modules, libraries, or classes in my project access this LCD module. For example, the network handling part, inside its own class, that wants to write to the same display, how does it know where to write to?